# How to build differently but with the same package.json?

Tags: git, heroku, version-control

I have 2 versions (branches) of my app: master and dev. They are hosted on different domains on Heroku.

I store sources in Bitbucket and then use pipeline to deploy to Heroku. It's very convenient but I have a problem that I can't tell BB to build differently. In package.json there is a line that should be different:

**for production (master):**

```
"scripts": {
        "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
    },
```

**for dev:**

```
"scripts": {
        "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js"
    },
```

As the result I want to have compiled, compressed JavaScript code on production and debuggable, uncompressed - on dev.

I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

I tried to have 2 different versions of package.json using git **.gitattributes** and **merge=ours**. But it has 2 pitfalls:

1. I still have conflict when I merge and I have to edit this file all the time.
2. If I install some new package on dev, package.json will be updated automatically but prod has its own version and the building will fail because it doesn't have the updated list of packages.

What is the proper solution for this problem?

**Solution found!**

Thanks @piotr.wittchen even although I use another solution he pushed me to find it.
It turned out I can use environment variables in the package.json https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up

So, I just changed the line in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.$env.js"
    },
```

The env variable is "dev" in the Heroku development app, and "prod" in the prod, and it's working like charm, no need to have different versions of the same file.

Comment: I'm not an expert in terms of JavaScript projects, but is it possible to export this setting to a separate file and then import it in `package.json`? If yes, then you can have separate file for production/dev environment with this `postbuild` command, but one file for remaining configuration. That would be the most reasonable option.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen I thought about this option but I don't know how to implement it. Probably, I should create a separate question for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change line in the package.json and put *env* variable there which is different for the different apps ("dev" and "prod"):

```
"scripts": {
        "heroku-postbuild": "webpack --config webpack.$env.js"
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I played with `npm` for a while and here's my proposal of the solution for this problem:

Create a bash script named `heroku-post-build.sh`.

For `master` branch, it should have contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
webpack --config webpack.prod.js
```

and for `dev` branch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
webpack --config webpack.dev.js
```

Inside the `heroku-postbuild` target invoke a bash script as follows:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "./heroku-post-build.sh"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The problem will be in the situation when you want to merge `dev` into `master` because it will override the script. In such case, you'll need to do git cherry picking.

Another approach (which is IMO better) is to create 2 targets like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild-dev":  "webpack --config webpack.dev.js"
    "heroku-postbuild-prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and invoke appropriate target according to the situation. Then, you won't have problems with merges. I don't know if it's feasible in your project setup.

Comment: It's also nice approach!